# Laravel middleware doesn't store the session value

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, middleware

I try to put my language in session(), but when I check session: `dd(session()->get('locale'));` - it's null. I have no idea why. I need to store that value in session.

my middleware:

```
class LangSwitch {
...
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
        if(!session()->has('locale')){
            $locale = $request->segment(1);
            session()->put('locale', $locale);    
        }
        else{
            $locale = session()->get('locale');
        }

        if (!array_key_exists($locale, Config::get('app.locales'))) {
            $segments = $request->segments();
            $segments[0] = Config::get('app.fallback_locale');

            return redirect()->to(implode('/', $segments));
        }

        App::setlocale($locale);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

my kernel:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\LangSwitch::class,
    ],
```

Comment: Did you assigned this middleware to any route ?

Comment: sure. I added group(['middleware' => 'web'] for my routes

Comment: share `protected $routeMiddleware = [`  value from kernel ?

Comment: protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'mylang' => \App\Http\Middleware\LangSwitch::class,
    ];

Answer (score 0):

let's try this

it will work

```
\Session::save();
```

Whenever you want to save the modification so lets say I want to store the language of the user

```
\Session::put('lang','en');
\Session::save();
```

Comment: No, this didn't help.